# Navigation Drawer drawerItemClickListener runs automatically. How can i avoid it?

Tags: android, onclick, navigation-drawer

I have a ListView menu with Navigation Drawer. If i run the application the drawerItemClickListener runs automatically with the first element. I know this is obvious because of the function is called when i create it, but i dont know how to avoid it.

In MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
}

private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
              long id) {
        // do something

    }
}
```

Comment: I've not see now to avoid this, what I've done is after creation call your handleItemSelect() with the position you want to show at first.  handleItemSelect() would be called in your onItemClick(), but declared outside the listener.

Comment: so you face with the same problem before but the only way to solve this to set the default menu element

Comment: Yeah that's what I've chalked it up to.  I'm gonna follow the topic, and if anyone posts a real answer I'd be very excited.